# Why do I get "Uninitialized Constant" from Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created a route:

```
user_currency GET    /user/currency/:currency(.:format)        user#currency
```

This is my User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
require 'will_paginate/array' 
require 'gdata'       
before_filter :ensure_user_friendly_url, :only => [:show, :following, :followers, :friends, :designers]
before_filter :check_if_signed_in, :only => :signup
```

And a controller for the route:

```
def currency
session[:currency] = params[:currency]
redirect_to :back
end
```

I am getting an error:

```
uninitialized constant UserController
```

The error occurs here:

```
- currency_values.each do |currency|
    %li 
      = link_to "#{currency.country}", user_currency_url(currency.id)
```

I am passing `currency_id` as currency.

Comment: can you paste the rest of the UserController?

Comment: `class UsersController < ApplicationController ` means your class is `UsersController` just checj your file name must be `users_controller.rb` and not `user_controller.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route declaration you refer to the controller name incorrectly. It should be:

```
user_currency GET    /user/currency/:currency(.:format)        users#currency
```

Basically your controller is `UsersController` not `UserController`.